# imagettftext() in php is not mixing char in devanagari

Tags: php, gd

I am trying to write text in devanagari on image. But some characters are not mixing. For example

> If we have to write 'प्रवेश' in devanagari on image
> we are getting प् रवेः

Below is my code

```
$name = 'प्रवेशः';
$image = imagecreatefromjpeg('image.jpeg');
  $font_path ='./NotoSansDevanagari-VariableFont_wdth_wght.ttf';
  $red_color = imagecolorallocate($image,240, 71, 50);
  //name to write
  imagettftext($image,30,0,630,425,$red_color, $font_path, $name );

  // Turn off alpha blending and set alpha flag
  imagealphablending($image, false);
  imagesavealpha($image, true);

  header("Content-type:image/jpeg");
  imagejpeg($image);
  imagedestroy($image);
```

I have googled my problem and got to know it is having some bug
[bugs.php.net](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=34670)

Is there any way to solve this problem?